# Is there a way to get a list/array of a user's ad group memberships using KUSTO?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I know I can check group memberships using current_principal_is_member_of()

but I need to get a list of the groups in order to use them later on in a query, is there any way to retrieve a user's group memberships using KUSTO?

How can I get a list of users group names like

```
["XXXX","YYYY","ZZZZ","AAAA","BBBB","CCCC","DDDD"]
```

where each value is a group from Azure AD

Making a static table like this works

```
datatable (groupfromaad:string) [
"group1",
"group2"
]
```

But how do I make the datatable dynamic with a real query to the AD for the current user?

Comment: The code does not seem to make much sense. Please add a sample data + required results, both in datatable/CSV format.

Comment: You can't. Even if you retrieve the data using the http_request / http_request_post plugins, still plugins accept only hard-coded arguments. What would you have done with the list if you were able to get it?

Comment: I would use that list to filter the data the user should have access to, I do this today but I maintain tables for the properties and it works fine its just a bit tiresome to maintain where as AD groups would be nice

Comment: Why can't you use `current_principal_is_member_of()` for that?

Comment: thats my nest question :) I rewrote the code but is having an issue will put a new question up shortly

Comment: Forget about the code. The question should be very simple: sample data + required results, both in datatable/CSV format. if the transformation logic is not trivial, then add a sentence or two explaining it. That's all.

Comment: posted the query with datatable and the problem